# Sharing a java object across a cluster

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, cluster-computing

My requirement is to share a java object across a cluster.

I get Confused

- whether to write an EJB and share the java objects across the cluster
  or
- to use any third party such as infinispan or memecached or terracotta or
- what about JCache?

with the constraint that

- I can't change any of my source code with specific to any application
  server (such as implementing the weblogic's singleton services).
- I can't offer two builds for cluster and non cluster environment.
- Performance should not be downgraded.
- I am looking for only open source third party if I need to use it.
- It need to work in weblogic , Websphere , Jbos and Tomcat too.

Can any one come up with the best option with these constraints in mind.

Answer (score 4):

It can depend on the use case of the objects you want to share in the cluster.

I think it comes down to really the following options in most complex to least complex

**Distributed cacheing** 
http://www.ehcache.org

Distributed cacheing is good if you need to ensure that an object is accessible from a cache on every node.  I have used ehache to distribute quite successfully, no need to setup a terracotta server unless you need the scale, can just point instances together via rmi.  Also works synchronously and asynchronously depending on requirements.  Also cache replication is handy if nodes go down so cache is actually redundant and dont lose anything.  Good if you need to make sure that the object has been updated across all the nodes.

**Clustered Execution/data distribution**
http://www.hazelcast.com/

Hazelcast is also a nice option as provides a way of executing java classes across a cluster.  This is more useful if you have an object that represents a unit of work that needs to be performed and you dont care so much where it gets executed.

Also useful for distributed collections, i.e. a distributed map or queue

**Roll your own RMI/Jgroups**

Can write your own client/server but I think you will start to run into issues that the bigger frameworks solve if the requirements of the objects your dealing with starts to get complex.  Realistically Hazelcast is really simple and should really eliminate the need to roll your own.

Comment: Is there a generic API which works with all J2EE compliant servers? what about JCache JSR 107 ?

Comment: I've been researching and looking at Terracotta in order to have a way to make applications share objects across JVM processed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63926180/using-terracotta-for-distributed-shared-java-objects

Answer (score 1):

It's not open source, but Oracle Coherence would easily solve this problem.

If you need an implementation of JCache, the only one that I'm aware of being available today is Oracle Coherence; see: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_part.htm

*For the sake of full disclosure, I work at Oracle. The opinions and views expressed in this post are my own, and do not necessarily reflect the opinions or views of my employer.*

Answer (score 0):

- It is just an idea. you might want to check the exact implementation.
- It will downgrade performance but I don't see how it is possible to avoid it.
- It not an easy one to implement. might be you should consider load balance instead of clustering.

you might consider RMI and/or dynamic-proxy.

- extract interface of your objects.
- use RMI to access the real object (from all clusters even the one that actually holds the object)
- in order to create RMI for an existing code you might use dynamic-proxy (again..not sure about implementation)

*dynamic proxy can wrap any object and do some pre and post task on each method invocation. in this case it might use the original object for RMI invocation

- you will need connectivity between clusters in order to propogate the RMI object.

Comment: Is there a generic API which works with all J2EE compliant servers? what about JCache JSR 107 ?